# how to apply patch files in wso2 carbon

Tags: wso2

Can someone please run through the steps that you need to follow to apply .patch files onto WSO2 ESB v4.0.3? I've tried the following:

1. Upload `.patch` file to `repository/components/patches` and
   carbon_home/lib/patches
2. Run `wso2server.sh start -DapplyPatches`

This command creates a dir called `patch000` in the components/patches directory and fills it with plugins.

The patch I want to apply is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TRANSPORTS-51

Many thanks

Answer (score 10):

You need to apply .patch file to the code base and create jar(s) out of it. Then  Create a folder with the name of the patch (eg: patch001) and place the jar(s) inside and copy newly created patch folder (eg: patch001) to repository/components/patches. 
Now running the wso2server.sh -DapplyPatches will work.

when you execute -DapplyPatches, it takes a backup of the original content of the repository/components/plugins directory to repository/components/patches directory that's why you see patch000 folder (hence revert-back to a previous state is possible).

Comment: I have to apply a patch to ESB-4.6.0. The source is available for download? And there's some tutorial explaining how to generate the jar? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From carbon 4.2.0 onwards you don't need to provide -DapplyPatches option in order to apply the patch. When a server started up it automatically detects and apply if there are new patches. 
This can be verified from the log file repository/logs/patches.log

Answer (score 3):

**WSO2 Official patch,**

1. Read the readme file.(not a must step, better if you do)
2. Shutdown the server, if you have already started.
3. Copy the wso2carbon-version.txt file to /bin.(not a must step,better if you do)
4. Copy the patchNumber to  /repository/components/patches/
5. Restart the server with :
      Linux/Unix :  sh wso2server.sh
      Windows    :  wso2server.bat

**Patch Created by you**

Compile(`mvn clean install`) and get the jar from the modified code base. for example, let's say you are creating a patch for carbon-registry [extensions](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry/tree/master/components/registry/org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions). First, clone the carbon-registry and do the fix then go to the [extensions](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry/tree/master/components/registry/org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions) module. Using maven build(`mvn clean install`) the jar. Then Create a folder with the name of the patch (eg: patch9999) and place the jar(s) inside and copy newly created patch folder (eg: patch9999) to `repository/components/patches`. Now simply restart/start the product and the patch will get applied.

```
./wso2server.sh restart/start
```

However, if the product is older than carbon 4.2.0 you have to provide -DapplyPatches attribute when starting the product like below.

```
./wso2server.sh -DapplyPatches
```

if the patch gets applied successfully you can see below set of lines in the beginning.

```
[2016-08-24 20:27:25,319]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.PatchInstaller} -  Patch changes detected 
[2016-08-24 20:27:27,980]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.server.util.PatchUtils.console} -  Backed up plugins to patch0000
[2016-08-24 20:27:28,010]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.server.util.PatchUtils.console} -  Patch verification started
[2016-08-24 20:27:28,034]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.server.util.PatchUtils.console} -  Patch verification successfully completed.
```

Comment: Very good first point! Because there are patches that must be applied manually - described then in the readme file!

Answer (score -1):

As Sajith says, we have added -DapplyPatches as JVM parameter by default in wso2server.sh file.