# What version of WSO2 Carbon should we be trying to build?

Tags: wso2

We're spending quite some effort in getting Carbon to build and having very mixed success with that.

What we want to have in the end (for now at least) is BAM + CEP. We started to experiment with the pre-built packages that can be downloaded and noticed that if we downloaded the BAM package we could add CEP only if we were running version 2.2.0 (not for the latest 2.3.0 of the BAM package). On closer inspection we noticed that CEP only seems to exist in Carbon platform 4.0.x and not in 4.1.x.

See:
http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.7/products/
vs.
http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.1.5/products/

So the basic question is, why does CEP not exist in 4.1.x? Will it be added later and if so when? Is it the correct strategy to be spending the effort on getting 4.0.x to compile since we need CEP or should we rather be getting 4.1.x to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a Carbon platform release goes with a specific set of products (not all). you can find out which carbon version contains which product versions [from the release matrix here](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/).

The current version of CEP has been released with Carbon 4.0.7 [as given in the release matrix](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/) (which is why it doesn't exist in 4.1.x). So you should be looking at that version if you are going to modify/build CEP from the code. Similarly for building other products you can follow the same approach. Note that it is not necessary to checkout the whole codebase in order to do a modification, you can checkout/modify/build the necessary components and apply it as a patch ([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306929/how-to-apply-patch-files-in-wso2-carbon)).

And when there's a new version of a product, it usually goes with a new release version of the Carbon platform.