# Session Timeout in WSO2 4.1.1

Tags: wso2

We are using WSO2 4.1.1 for user management. Is there a way to do a session time out in WSO2 4.1.1? 
(I am looking if there is a fix for this in WSO2 4.1.1. Currently, I am not looking at migrating to WSO2 4.5 
where this is mentioned as a supported feature).

I am referring to the following link where it says the WSO2 4.1.1.code has been changed to handle session time out.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-1030

Are these changes available as a new version of jar compatible with the WSO2 4.1.1 version?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get a new version of the jar and use it with the WSO2 IS 4.1.1. AFAIK, IS 4.1.1 was never [released](http://wso2.com/more-downloads/identity-server/), I think you are using a build shared via dev@ list.

Anyway, you can try following.

1. Checkout the source for the corresponding jars in WSO2 IS 4.1.1. Try to checkout from branch. For example: https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.1.0/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.base/
2. Fix the issue and do 'mvn clean install'
3. Copy the target jar as a [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306929/how-to-apply-patch-files-in-wso2-carbon).
4. Run server with -DapplyPatches

In this way, you can try to fix this issue.

If we discover issues with any product after it has been released, you will be able to get the fix only in a newer version. Otherwise, you need to patch the existing jar versions.

I hope this helps.