# Error while building WSO2 components

Tags: wso2

I had issue with wso2 posted @ [Session Timeout in WSO2 4.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366369/session-timeout-in-wso2-4-1-1.Please) note that I do not have experience in maven and trying WSO2 for the first time.

As per the response , tried out the following.

I got the code from the location, https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/identity
and tried to build using the command. mvn clean install

I am getting the error as below.

[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.wso2.carbon:identity:4.2.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifa
ct org.wso2.carbon:carbon-components:pom:4.2.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong lo
cal POM @ org.wso2.carbon:identity:4.2.0-SNAPSHOT, D:\wso2\pom.xml, line 19, column 13

```
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:364)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:637)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:586)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:229)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)\
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: if you are trying to fix a bug and apply it as a patch for an older version... do it with the relevant branch (not trunk coz trunk contains latest code and can be incompatible). you can find which version maps to which carbon version from here: http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/

Answer (score 0):

Please try building the directory https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/ first which will resolve the parent pom.