# WSO2 ESB FORCE_HTTP_1.0 not working

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, http-1.0, wso2-esb

I'm trying to force the WSO2 to set the http version to 1.0 because the client of a service requires the `Content-Length` property. I configured the following properties in the `outSequence`, before the `<send/>`:

```
<property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

but it doesn't works! The response header:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
userAgent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO
Host: localhost:8280
SOAPAction: "sendMessage"
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
Date: Thu, 13 Mar 2014 21:55:25 GMT
Connection: Close
```

I'm using ESB 4.6.0 and SoapUI to call the service.
Why the `Content-Length` doesn't appears? What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in ESB and we fixed it recently.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2985

The properties you mentioned are not working in `outSequence` path.

The fix should be available in next release.

The patch for Synapse transport is also attached in [ESBJAVA-2985](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2985) and you may [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306929/how-to-apply-patch-files-in-wso2-carbon) the Synapse version in your WSO2 ESB.

Comment: The source of the version 4.6.0 is not available for download.

Comment: All WSO2 code is open source and available at SVN https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/. It's just the link to specific tag is missing in the web site. Do you have intention of patching? If so, I can give you instructions.

Comment: Any reasons for using ESB 4.6.0? Is it possible to use ESB 4.8.1?

Comment: Thanks for answer Isuru. There's some tutorial? I would appreciate if you help me to apply this patch.

Comment: And I'm using 4.6.0 because it's the version currently approved for run here on the company.

Comment: The synapse version used in ESB 4.6.0 is https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/dependencies/synapse/2.1.1-wso2v2/. So we need to checkout this and create the patch

Comment: Where I should execute the `mvn install`? And what is the required maven version?

Comment: You should be able to build from the path I gave. Please use Maven 3.0.5 and Oracle JDK 1.6.

Comment: This patch causes compiler errors. The class `MessageProcessorSelector` was not found.

Comment: I didn't get much time to look at the code. There can be lot of changes between ESB 4.6.0 Synapse and ESB 4.8.0 Synapse. We have to carefully check and patch.

Comment: That class was added to axis2 in the version 1.6.1-wso2v8. The pom.xml references the 1.6.1-wso2v7.

Comment: Finally worked! But I had to change the files manually following the patch logic. Thanks Isuru.

Comment: Hi, I am currently using WSO2 and because of it using HTTP/2 by default on token timeout my stream is not closing. Can you please help me out here and let me know how can I ensure WSO2 does not using HTTP/2. Note I am only using the api manager and not the ESB